# Opsworks install composer error

Tags: ruby, composer-php, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I have an AWS Opsworks setup where I need to install composer on instance start and app deployment, but the installation fails. Can anyone help me out soving this.
I'm running this Chef recipe:

```
node[:deploy].each do |app_name, deploy|
  script "install_composer" do
    interpreter "bash"
    user "ubuntu"
    cwd "#{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current"
    code <<-EOH
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
    php composer.phar install --no-dev
    EOH
    only_if { ::File.exists?("#{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current/composer.json") }
  end
end
```

I'm receiving the following errors (where line 21 is the one that with `script "install_composer" do`).

```
[2017-01-18T11:16:38+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2017-01-18T11:16:38+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2017-01-18T11:16:38+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/chef-stacktrace.out
[2017-01-18T11:16:38+00:00] ERROR: script[install_composer] (composer::install line 21) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20170118-1672-16lyp81" ----
STDOUT: All settings correct for using Composer
The installation directory "/srv/www/[app_name]/releases/20170113140255" is not writable
Could not open input file: composer.phar
STDERR: 
---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20170118-1672-16lyp81" ----
Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20170118-1672-16lyp81" returned 1
[2017-01-18T11:16:38+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

I used a combination of these examples to build the script:

https://github.com/awslabs/opsworks-example-cookbooks/blob/master/phpapp/recipes/appsetup.rb
https://github.com/onema/opsworks-chef-cookbooks/blob/master/composer/recipes/install.rb

The setup runs on Ubuntu instances. The instance reports `setup_failed`. If I disable the custom recipes, the instance starts fine.

The app which name shows in the `The installation directory "/srv/www/[app_name]/releases/20170113140255" is not writable` is the 4th app in my app list, but the first one that it should actually install composer on (it contains `composer.json`).

Hope you can help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it when I realized that the user was supposed to be "root" and not "ubuntu" in the recipe. The ubuntu user simply did not have adequate rights to create new folders in the release folder.